# Minimal makefile to build a Solana program in C?

Tags: sdk

So the Solana [helloworld](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/blob/master/src/program-c/makefile) example has a makefile that includes a [much bigger makefile](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/sbf/c/sbf.mk) that does helpful things like generating make targets based on the names of your programs.

This also makes it much harder for me to understand what commands are even being run. Does anyone have a barebones example that might be less ergonomic but is easier to follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a bit bored and trimmed down the makefile a lot! It's definitely confusing since it's pretty much doing all of `cargo build-sbf` for a whole workspace, but I hope this should be easy to follow. You pretty much just need to `clang` on the C file to produce the O file, then `ld.lld` on the O file to make the SO file.

You can thin out some more of the includes, but those might become important depending on your future use-case. Let me know how it works for you!

```
LOCAL_PATH := /home/$(USER)/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/sdk/sbf/c/

.PHONY: all clean

SRC_DIR ?= ./src
OUT_DIR ?= ./out

all: $(OUT_DIR)/helloworld/helloworld.so

clean:
  rm -rf $(OUT_DIR)

LLVM_DIR = $(LOCAL_PATH)../dependencies/platform-tools/llvm
LLVM_SYSTEM_INC_DIRS := $(LLVM_DIR)/lib/clang/15.0.4/include
STD_INC_DIRS := $(LLVM_DIR)/include
STD_LIB_DIRS := $(LLVM_DIR)/lib

CC := $(LLVM_DIR)/bin/clang
LLD := $(LLVM_DIR)/bin/ld.lld

SYSTEM_INC_DIRS := \
  $(LOCAL_PATH)inc \
  $(LLVM_SYSTEM_INC_DIRS) \

C_FLAGS := \
  -Werror \
  -O2 \
  -fno-builtin \
  -std=c17 \
  $(addprefix -isystem,$(SYSTEM_INC_DIRS)) \
  $(addprefix -I,$(STD_INC_DIRS)) \
  -target sbf \
  -fPIC

SBF_LLD_FLAGS := \
  -z notext \
  -shared \
  --Bdynamic \
  $(LOCAL_PATH)sbf.ld \
  --entry entrypoint \
  -L $(STD_LIB_DIRS) \
  -lc \

$(OUT_DIR)/helloworld/helloworld.o: $(SRC_DIR)/helloworld/helloworld.c
  mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)/helloworld
  $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $(OUT_DIR)/helloworld/helloworld.o -c $(SRC_DIR)/helloworld/helloworld.c

$(OUT_DIR)/helloworld/helloworld.so: $(OUT_DIR)/helloworld/helloworld.o
  $(LLD) $(SBF_LLD_FLAGS) -o $(OUT_DIR)/helloworld/helloworld.so $(OUT_DIR)/helloworld/helloworld.o
```

Side note: After typing the word "helloworld" so many times, it has ceased to mean anything.

Comment: When I run `make` I get a make error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'src/helloworld.c', needed by 'out/helloworld.o'.  Stop`

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear in my original answer.  You need to have `helloworld.c` in `src`, and not in `src/helloworld`. I changed the answer so you can just use it directly in example-helloworld/src/program-c

Comment: ah ok great, works now

Comment: The README states that there is a single .c file limitation per program, why is that?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be correct. I modified the above example to include another file and linked them together into a `.so` no problem. Maybe they mean that the makefile doesn't let you do it by default?